# Can all GUI linux apps be made to work using an X server?

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux

I recently saw a [post](https://www.reddit.com/r/Windows10/comments/4ea4w4/fyi_you_can_run_gui_linux_apps_from_bash/) where it was mentioned that gui linux apps can work by running an X server outside of bash.

So I tried to make sublime text editor 2 work using this concept but was not able to do so.

Is my bash faulty or is there any other problem?

Comment: *"using this concept"* - you will need to tell us what you actually did

Comment: First I downloaded xming from [here](https://sourceforge.net/projects/xming/) .. Then I installed sublime text using sudo apt-get command.. Afterwards I typed DISPLAY=:0 subl ......It gave error

Comment: Ubuntu does not provide Sublime Text as a package via apt, are you using Linux Mint? If so, which version?

Comment: I am using bash on ubuntu on windows

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are the steps I did to get sublimetext3 working on bash. It's great because like this you can edit files from bash without corrupting them.

install and run VcxSrv for Windows from
https://sourceforge.net/projects/vcxsrv/

then on bash:

```
sudo apt install gimp
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/sublime-text-3 -y
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install sublime-text-installer
DISPLAY=:0 /opt/sublime_text/sublime_text
```

and you can create a desktop shortcut with this content:

```
C:\Windows\System32\bash.exe ~ -c "DISPLAY=:0 /opt/sublime_text/sublime_text"
```

BTW gimp it's an image editor that contains the libraries (gtk) for sublime_text you can also run it typing:

```
DISPLAY=:0 gimp
```

Comment: is there a way that enables me to just write DISPLAY=:0 sublime_text to open it.(I didn't get the create desktop shortcut thing).    Also will it work with    Xming also because I have Xming installed

Comment: Xming should also work, yes. If you have Xming running in the background (you will see its icon on the system tray) then you can just type DISPLAY=:0 sublime_text on bash and it will open sublime. The important part is the Xming/VcxSrv should be running in order to a window application to appear.

Comment: DISPLAY=:0 /opt/sublime_text/sublime_text is the correct command if you don't have /opt/sublime_text/ in the PATH variable.

Answer (score 1):

Although there may be a better place to make this change, I add the following line to the file /etc/bash.bashrc to make most X11 apps work (after you've installed and started Xming):

```
export DISPLAY=localhost:0.0
```

You will have to save the file then close/open bash again for it to take effect. Then run an X-based app.