# Where is the Trash folder in Ubuntu/Windows (WSL)?

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux, trash

I am using **Ubuntu in Win10**, but I can not find the trash folder, even when I use the command

```
mv ~/.Trash/foo ~/
mv: cannot stat '/home/man/.Trash/foo': No such file or directory
```

My question is that how can I open trash folder in Ubuntu/Win10?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Trash** is located in `~/.local/share/Trash`, at least in Ubuntu. `~/.local` – or more precisely, `~/.local/share` – is where XDG-compliant programs store user data (e.g., fonts, mail messages) according to the [XDG Base Directory specification](http://standards.freedesktop.org/basedir-spec/basedir-spec-latest.html).

Ubuntu on WSL only provides you with a ***terminal and no GUI by default***.

Whenever a file is deleted from a graphical file manager in Ubuntu like Nautilus or Thunar, they are actually moved into `~/.local/share/Trash`. Files are usually deleted using `rm` from the terminal, which *doesn't **move** them to the Trash folder*.

So there is no trash folder in WSL unless you use a Linux graphical file manager.

Comment: It is a falsehood that graphical user interfaces do not exist in the WSFL.  https://askubuntu.com/questions/808474/  It is a falsehood that `.local` is tied to graphical user interfaces.

Comment: At least as of WSL under Ubuntu 20.04 the trash is in the usual location `~/.local/share/Trash`.

Answer (score 3):

My WSL (Ubuntu-20.04) didn't have a ~/.local/share/Trash folder.
I followed the instructions here (https://github.com/sindresorhus/trash) and installed
`trash` and `trash-cli` with `npm`.

Things like these work now!

```
[username@host]$ tldr trash
trash
A CLI for managing your trashcan / recycling bin.More information: https://github.com/andreafrancia/trash-cli.

 - Delete a file (send to trash):
   trash {{path/to/file}}

 - List files in trash:
   trash-list

 - Restore file from trash:
   trash-restore

 - Empty trash:
   trash-empty

 - Empty trash, keeping files trashed less than {{10}} days ago:
   trash-empty {{10}}

 - Remove all files named 'foo' from the trash:
   trash-rm foo

 - Remove all files with a given original location:
   trash-rm {{/absolute/path/to/file_or_directory}}
```

Tip: https://github.com/tldr-pages/tldr is a really cool tool to get practical examples of commands that manual pages usually don't have.

Answer (score 1):

The Trash folder in Ubuntu is typically provided by `gio` (Gnome IO) and GVfs (the Gnome Virtual Filesystem).   While applications like Nautilus act on the GVfs to access the trash, it can also be done directly from the command-line on WSL or Ubuntu Server, without any GUI, using the `gio` commandline tool.

It *does*, however, require a D-Bus user session, which does not run automatically under WSL since there's (a) no Systemd and (b) no concept of "login" during which to start user services.

While `gio` and D-bus are both installed by default in the WSL Ubuntu distribution, you do need to add the `gvfs` package (at least on WSL):

```
sudo apt install gvfs
```

Then you need to launch your shell with D-Bus support.  This can be done multiple ways, but perhaps the best option is to change your WSL launch command (in Windows Terminal or elsewhere) to:

```
wsl ~ -e dbus-launch bash # Or your preferred shell
```

At this point, you can use the Trash from the WSL command line.  Example:

```
touch "a test file"
gio trash "a test file"
gio list Trash://
ls -lah ~/.local/share/Trash/files
gio trash --empty
gio list Trash://
ls -lah ~/.local/share/Trash/files
```